# Slidable tab navigation depending on the screen size

Tags: android, user-interface, tabs

I am looking for a Tab navigation UI component that would work similarly to the [SlidingPaneLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html), i.e. would **show as many tabs as possible and make the tabs slidable left/right when the tabs wouldn't fit on the screen** (in my case its tablets vs smartphones case). An example of it would be [Slideable top navigation UI pattern](http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/slideable-top-navigation).

Is there any library I could use to implement such component in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Action bar tabs and ViewPager are the one's you are looking for. These are in built feature of Android, Easy to access and backward compatible to earlier versions as well.

ActionBar tabs is the one that will give you the tab like feature.

ViewPager on the other hand will provide the functionality of swipe.

[Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/) is a step by step example on both.